# Resizing NSView when application window resizes

Tags: cocoa

I've been really struggling with this one.

I have an application which has a custom view. When the application starts, I set the custom view's frame size to the application window's frame size. This works. In the AppDelegate.m, I am loading another view controller's view into the custom view. In the view of the view controller, I have an image which is placed at the center of the screen programatically. I have a windowDidResize method in my AppDelegate.m which gets called when I resize the application's window.

The problem is when I resize the application's window, the image does not get repositioned in the center of the main window. I tried using NSWindowDelegate on both the loaded view and the view controller with coding a windowDidResize: method, but this also does not work.

Please help!
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried setting up constraints ?

Comment: I cannot use constraints because I want to position objects on the view dynamically as well.

Comment: For posterity, I had a similar issue; in this case, I would suggest first looking at `autoresizingMask`.  Programmatically, `windowDidResize` is probably the wrong place since it is intended for clean up operations, especially with live resizing.  For custom view resizing, look at `resizeWithOldSuperviewSize`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a hack, but what I do is capture the initial window frame etc size as an ivar at an 'init' method; I then use this to scale any x/y/height/width measuring at run-time.

```
//  Handy scaling macros
#define X(xVal)         ((xVal) * (x_scale))
#define Y(yVal)         ((yVal) * (y_scale))
```

Each window's delegate handler for size changes:

```
- (void)set_scales:(NSSize)size
{
    self.x_scale = (CGFloat)(size.width)  / (CGFloat)(orig.width);
    self.y_scale = (CGFloat)(size.height) / (CGFloat)(orig.height);
}
```

and those windows have their def/undef of x/y_scale macros will simply return these ivars. So all told, each window has a NSSize orig, CGFloat x,y, a scale delegate method, two macros (x/y_scale) and two global macros X,Y.

Then whenever drawing etc, use the X() and Y() macros to position and affect h/w. i.e.,

```
[@"foo" drawAtPoint:NSMakePoint(X(100),Y(200)) withAttributes:nil];
```